# Connecting to Amazon RDS through a java client using AmazonRDSClientBuilder

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-rds

I am trying to work with AmazonRDS (mysql) . With regular jdbc connection setup in a spring-boot application connecting, doing CRUD operations works without issues. I am exploring on AmazonRDS java SDK; I would like to use AmazonRDSClientBuilder/AmazonRDSAsyncClientBuilder to do the above operations. I couldn't find much examples out there, is there any one who tried this approach ? Is there a good reference link / documentation I can take help of to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AmazonRDSClient`, and all the other RDS stuff in the SDK, is for creating and managing RDS database resources. You don't use the SDK for querying RDS databases and performing CRUD operations. JDBC is the correct, and only way for performing CRUD operations against your MySQL database in your Java application.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to upvote your answer, appreciate your input

Comment: @user2427771 note that this is actually the correct answer to your question.  The SDK for RDS interacts only with the provisioning and management APIs, not the database itself.  It's not a database client.  This is in contrast to many other services (such as DynamoDB) where the SDK can handle all interactions with the service.  RDS uses standard tools and libraries (e.g. JDBC) for actual DML (CRUD) and DDL.